# Fail to use 'Remote Desktop connection' with display size 3840x2160

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have setup a Hyper-V Windows VM on my Windows 10 machine. 
When I run that Windows VM and then i try to remote in using 'Remote Desktop connection', I cant' get connected if i set the Display configuration using 3840x2160. But if I change the Display configuration in 'Remote Desktop Connection' to 2560x1600, it works.

Can you please tell me how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to increase the amount of video RAM for the virtual machine.  Doing so will allow you to use higher resolutions and color depths.

I only found one really good link that talks about it [here](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/remotefx-windows-10-client-hyper-v/)

Comment: Thanks. When i try add 'RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter' to my VM. It said 'We no longer support the RemoteFX 3D video adapter. You can keep usin gthis adapter on existing VMs, but you can't apply it to any new VMs'

Comment: That's weird, I was able to add one on my win10 box.

Comment: Solution here: https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperV/comments/9b7kil/hyperv_no_longer_supports_remotefx_3d/

Answer (score -1):

Check the maximum resolution supported by this remote session and the maximum resolution supported by this monitor itself.

The resolution of the current display itself needs to be equal to the resolution of the current remote session.

Whether the maximum resolution supported by the display itself can be adjusted to 3840x2160, if possible, adjust the resolution of the display to 3840x2160, and change the Display configuration in 'Remote Desktop Connection' to 3840x2160, then try to connecd through the remote desktop connection.

Comment: That's not true. You can succesfully connect to a remote desktop with a resolution higher than your monitor supports. It will generate scrollbars and using Smart Size, you can make the image scalable. Something else is going wrong here.